# Mach-o link errors

Tags: ios, xcode

I am using some third party libraries in my iOS application (libraries are flurry, chartboost and burstly). All those third party libraries have static libraries, and I included them in my project by adding them in "Link Binary with libraries".

However, when I try running my app, xcode shows lots of linker errors of the form

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50", referenced from:
    +[Burstly_iad_Adaptor initializeContentSizeIdentifiers] in    
libBurstly_AllNetworks_Latest.a(Burstly_iad_Adaptor.o)
```

It seems like I am missing something, in including those static libraries. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must link that subproject to [iAd.Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/Reference/iAd_ReferenceCollection/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009705) before it can be compiled successfully.  When subprojects are added, they often don't have their dependencies set correctly.

Comment: That reduced number of link errors from 47 to 41. Still seeing lot of link errors. Pasting the first error. I forgot to mention, I also use TapJoy but that library doesn't include any static libraries

`Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_MPMovieDurationAvailableNotification", referenced from:
      -[TJCVideoLayer prepareVideoWithDelegate:videoURL:shouldStream:] in TJCVideoLayer.o
      -[TJCVideoLayer stopVideo] in TJCVideoLayer.o
      -[TJCVideoLayer cleanupVideo] in TJCVideoLayer.o
      -[BurstlyVideoViewController initWithVideoURL:delegate:visitButtonHidden:] in `

Comment: The namespace of the errors (the first two letters MP in this case), will tell you the abbreviation of the framework that's missing from that individual dependency.  In this case, you need to link TJCVideoPlayer to MediaPlayer.framework.

Comment: Thanks for that info. Very helpful, should be able to fix the link errors now

Comment: Absolutely.  I went through dependency hell today, no reason why anyone else should.

Comment: I started looking for where "Link Binary with libraries" information is stored.

It would be great if someone in the team figures out all the dependencies and commits that information, and rest of the team could use that information.

My teammate went through this, and solved it, and I am doing the same from square one. (We both work on a same project by cloning git repo)

Comment: Yeah, well it's not your fault.  Dependencies were never really solved in a concrete manner in any kind of environment or language.  I recommend some kind of documented procedure (maybe just a wiki page if you're using github) that details what dependencies use what frameworks.  It'll save huge amounts of time in the long run.  (That and TapJoy is kind of scum, so I wouldn't trust their frameworks as far as you could throw em' :p)

Comment: True, but what I meant was, is there a file XCode uses/reads to find out what system libraries should be linked to this project

e.g. is there a file which says


`include Ad.Framework`
`include Someother.system.Framework`

If there is such a file, it is sufficient to update that file, and everyone who clones the project will have enough information to include all system frameworks